# how to align 2+ <span> on single line

Tags: css, mustache, accelerated-mobile-page

Am using `mustache` to populate data on an AMP HTML page.

Here is the target HTML on Google's `ampb.in`: https://ampb.in/#z4sIphWxKIOfZtfqWTpm

The buttons open a related structure, but are null here for simplicity.

How to make the second and subsequent `<span>` elements work inline as part of a `<p>`.

Have tried `.keep-together {display: inline-block; float: left}` but that does not work.

If I remove the `mustache template` the `<span>` and `<button>` work as expected.

Since the application depends on using `mustache`, **how to make the inline elements work as they do without `mustache`?**

Comment: The spans are nested in separate `<p role="listitem">` tags, so shouldn't the paragraphs be inline?

Comment: not quite following you. there is only one `<p>` and (now) 2 `<span>`s nested in the single `<p>`. Without `mustache` they work inline as expected. With `mustache` the second <span> is forced to a new line. I'm trying to eliminate whatever is forcing the second <span> to the new line.

Comment: Mustache seems to add extra tags, just take a look at the HTML structure of the page you linked: https://prnt.sc/kixfho

Comment: ah so! thanks - did not know that. based on that fact, can you propose inline CSS that would modify the hidden CSS to allow inline <span>?

Comment: or do I need to take a different approach based on the injected `mustache` CSS?

Comment: I don't know much about mustache, but `p, .keep-together { display: inline; }` seems to do the trick if you remove the float property.

Comment: here's a version with your change: https://ampb.in/#rAuIKzxzaygw9S1k1H8y

Comment: Nope, you missed the `p,`  part of my code above. Your paragraph tags are still `display: block`.

Comment: Perfect. Please `answer` and i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mustache is adding enclosing `<p role="listitem">` tags to each of your `<span class="keep-together">` elements. By adding

```
p, .keep-together { display: inline; }
```

all text with buttons will show as one inline element.

Disclaimer: I do not know much about mustache, there might be an option to prevent the additional tags. This is merely a CSS work-around.

Comment: I have a related question that I'd like to direct to you in a new Stack post. Are you online so I can call it to your attention?

Comment: Just post your question, there are tons of people out there who might have better answers than I do. If you posted the question, you can still link it here as a comment, and I will get notified.